# Why the ISO C++ standard forbids string-literals to be contained in multi-lines but raw ones?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, iso, string-literals

Why you can write this:

```
R"rawdelim( Multi-Line
            Text )rawdelim"
```

But not this:

```
" Multi-Line
  Text "
```

Or what's the rationale of '2.13.5' (string literals) in ISO C++ 14 (draft):

[image: ISO C++ quote]

About the darkened text.

Comment: Because it's retarded regarding this feature. Older standards still let you continue string literal declarations using either `\\`  to escape newlines,  or `+` to aggregate `std::string``s.

Comment: Maybe it would make for ugly looking code if in every string you had to use multiple lines when your string contains line-breaks. Its more compact to use the escape sequence `\n`. Now we have a choice to use escaping or literally include everything between the delimiters.

Comment: My guess is it's legacy compatibility with the C pre-processor.   Imagine a multi-line literal with the 2nd line starting `#define`, or any other of the pre-processor directives.

Comment: Because failing to terminate a string on the same line is usually an error. There are still ways to split strings - a trailing backslash at the end of a line causes the two lines to be treated as one logically, and adjacent string literals (even on different lines) are automatically concatenated.